# Phonegap image picker from gallery not working properly

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I want to use a photo from gallery and then crop it. I am using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-imagepicker) plugin. It has absolutely no documentation so I need a bit help. On button click, I want to open the gallery and select an image and then crop it too. I made a function in my `myapp.js`

```
function uploadImage(){
    window.imagePicker.getPictures(
        function(results) {
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                console.log('Image URI: ' + results[i]);
            }
        }, function (error) {
            console.log('Error: ' + error);
        }, {
            maximumImagesCount: 10,
            width: 800
        }
    );
}
```

and i am calling it on button click.

```
<a href="#" onClick="uploadImage();">Upload</a>
```

But my app crashes.

> Unfortunately, App has stopped working.

What should I do?

Comment: Try adding `try - catch`  block into your code and check if you are getting any error or not. also set alert first to check function working perfectly or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use phonegap default camera plugin to get image and crop it. code is below which you can get easily from phongegap docs available in its official site.

```
function uploadImage(){
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
                sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY, 
                allowEdit: true,
                destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
                });
}
function onSuccess(imageURI){
                 var image = document.getElementById('smallimage');
                 image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," +imageURI;
            }

            function onFail(message){
            }
```

allowEdit option will give cropping option and you can even give fixed cropping width and height through below option.

```
     targetWidth: 400,targetHeight: 250,
```